# В чем разница между «доступ к» и «доступ в»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, предлоги

Какой вариант лучше?

*Эти виртуальные машины имеют доступ **в** интернет.

Эти виртуальные машины имеют доступ **к** интернету.*

Какой вариант чаще используется?

Answer (score 2):

В толковом словаре:
[до́ступ](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF), -а; ***м.***
**2.** Впуск, допуск куда-либо. *Получить доступ на завод, в архив. Доступ на перрон закрыт. Доступ посетителей прекращён. Дать доступ к уму, сердцу, душе, чувствам* (о возможности отклика, понимания, доверия). **//** *(к чему)*. Возможность пользоваться чем-либо, получать что-либо. *Получить доступ к секретным документам. Смотреть книги на открытом доступе* (самому брать книги с полок в библиотеке).

Статистика собственно в интернете показывает почти равное использование предлогов.
Статистика в Нацкорпусе такова:
*доступ **в** интернет* — 80, *доступ **к** интернету* — 52.
При выборе предлога в словосочетании, думаю, большую роль играет контекст.

• Если интернет уже имелся, но по каким-то причинам его "отрезали" (неуплата, блокировка), то чаще используется предлог **в**.

*Во время «арабской весны» Сирия отключила у себя **доступ в интернет**, желая предотвратить организацию повстанцев с помощью социальных сетей* (Александр Баулин. Кибербитва за Родину).

• Если же имеется в виду обеспечение интернетом вообще (вышки, аппаратура), то чаще используется предлог **к**.

*По данным Международного союза электросвязи, **доступ к интернету** имели 67,2% российских домохозяйств (больше, чем по данным Росстата), что соответствует уровню развитых стран* (Е. Н. Клочкова. Статистическое исследование ключевых индикаторов развития информационного общества в России).

• Конкретно про виртуальные машины... Даже и не знаю, что сказать.
*Виртуальная реальность* — это то, что подменяет, заменяет собой реальность; искусственная реальность.

Answer (score 0):

**Виртуальная машина имеет доступ к интернету** звучит лучше, из-за несуразности словосочетания **виртуальная машина в интернете**. Но другой вариант тоже возможен. В нем **доступ в интернет** выступает как цельное словосочетание